# How to display multiple static location in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am trying to show marker in different location from user current location in map.
Right now  i have given **two static value**

1.) `LatLng one = new LatLng(12.9010, 80.2279);`

2.) `LatLng two = new LatLng(12.9229, 80.1275);`
but it's not showing marker in map, I am getting console output has **lat long value 0,0.**

Here is the code i used for getting marker loaction in map by using static value.

```
private void addmap() {

    LatLng one = new LatLng(12.9010, 80.2279);
    LatLng two = new LatLng(12.9229, 80.1275);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    //add them to builder
    builder.include(one);
    builder.include(two);

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    //get width and height to current display screen
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    // 20% padding
    int padding = (int) (width * 0.20);

    //set latlong bounds
    Mmap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(bounds);

    //move camera to fill the bound to screen
    Mmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding));

    //set zoom to level to current so that you won't be able to zoom out viz. 
  move outside bounds
//        Mmap.setMinZoomPreference(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
}
```

Comment: Check your `width` and `height` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put lat long in a list and make a loop to set multiple markers

Here is the sample

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            Marker marker;
            marker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(list.getLat(), list.getLng()))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.location_other))
                        .flat(true));
           }
```